# Windows 10: Laptop display refuses to turn off

Tags: laptop, display, acpi, windows-10

System: Clevo P157SM (Sager NP8255-S).

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 Pro on my laptop and now the display refuses to turn off even if I lock the session or after the configured timeout (15 minutes on AC, 3 minutes on battery). It doesn't matter whether the laptop is plugged in.

The [Monoff](http://gizmoware.net/monoff/) utility causes the screen to switch off, but it comes back on immediately, suggesting spurious input from an input device. Turning off the trackpad and disconnecting any external mice or keyboard do not help.

The laptop has a hotkey which switches off the display at the firmware level; a key press on the onboard keyboard turns it back on. The display stays off with this feature, eliminating the keyboard as a possible cause; however, it bypasses the OS and it doesn't allow any kind of ACPI control.

I have no trouble putting the computer to sleep—the system stays asleep unless I wake it up. The computer will wake up from external device inputs but ignores input from the onboard keyboard and trackpad (this is normal) so this eliminates external hardware as a possibility.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

---

**Update:** The issue seems to be caused by a userspace app as the monitor does turn off if left idle before I log into the machine. How do I isolate the guilty application?

Comment: What's the laptop model?

Comment: you're talking for power saver to turn off monitor?

Comment: It seems that there aren't drivers for your laptop, for Windows 10. I've tried the manufacturer website and I got this: http://www.rightpromises.info/Downloads/P150SMA%20P151SMA%20P170SMA/Windows%208_1/ which may or may not work. I would try to play around with the chipset and the hotkey drivers. If possible, try to find an update on Intel's website for your chipset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in Windows 10 build 10586 released in November 2015. The display now turns off on its own when the machine is idle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
powercfg /batteryreport
```

And

```
powercfg /energy
```

From the command line. It would tell you potential issues with your power management.

See more at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PowerCfgTheHiddenEnergyAndBatteryToolForWindowsYoureNotUsing.aspx

Comment: The generated report doesn't seem to provide a useful explanation about what might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and it was caused by a microsoft bluetooth laptop, i pulled out the bluetooth dongle and that did solve the problem